# Showing that compact metrizable abelian group has enough characters

Tags: metric-spaces, abelian-groups, topological-groups, characters, duality-theorems

I want to know if anybody has some clue as why a compact metrizable abelian group has enough characters to separate points (a character on a topological group is a continuous homomorphism from the group to the circle group). Separate points means that if g is not 0, then there exists a character f such that f(g) is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known result from the theory of locally compact abelian groups. But I think that its proof should be complicated. For instance, in [Pon] this is a corollary from $\S$34.C, with a long full proof, which is based on irreducible matrix representations of compacts abelian groups, which are bases on integration with respect to invariant measures on these groups.

*References*

[Pon] Lev S. Pontrjagin, *Continuous groups*, 2nd ed., M., (1954) (in Russian).

Comment: There has to be some proof which is more basic. I hardly believe I need to know representations of compact abelian groups in order to prove this theorem.

Comment: @AvivEshed I think that we have to sufficiently know about the structure of a group in order to construct the characters.

Comment: If you know something about the Theory of Banach algebras (spectral radius formula), then one can prove this by showing that the characters correspond to the spectrum of $L^1(G)$ and then by using a part of the proof of Bochners theorem. If you are interested, I will post the proof.

Comment: @Alex That's very cool, using the Banach algebra stuff to show that characters _exist_. And you get all the characters that way. But I don't see how to use this to show the characters separate points. How do you show _a priori_ that $L^1(G)$ is semisimple? Or don't you need that? (My work so far: If $x\ne e$ but $\chi(x)=1$ for every character $\chi$ then the spectral radius of $f-\tau_x f$ is $0$ for every $f$, where $\tau_x$ is translation. That's impossible because why, exactly?)

Comment: @PhoemueX that would be great